# How to apply a filter in a REST Snap and hard code the value?

Tags: snaplogic

Suppose there is some data which I want to pass through the rest snap and in the query parameter I have given filter and in query parameter value I want to pass a hardcoded value. For example, "name .eq ", then what?

How can I give a hardcoded value in this filter option?

Comment: Can you show on postman what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass hard-coded values as it is. Refer to the following screenshot.

[image]

Just don't click on the expression button (the button with `=` on it) and you should be good.